# MySql returning only 1 row in page using print_r

Tags: php, mysql

I was doing this almost everyday, I think I am missing something here, my query is only returning one row on page.. but using the same query on the app 'Toad' on windows, it is returning all 7 team rows;

```
$db_host = 'myhost';
$db_user = 'user';
$db_pass = 'pass';
$db_name = 'db';

$db = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

$result = $db->query("SELECT `team_name`,`team_score` FROM `scores`");
$rowteams = $result->fetch_assoc();
//tried also this approach ---> $rowteams = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); 


print_r($rowteams);
```

//print_r output on page

```
Array ( [team_name] => Jay [team_score] => 0 )
```

nothing else.

This is the output on toad.

```
Jay  0
Ced 736
Abby 20
Jef 263
```

What may be the cause of this? T_T

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php  Fetch **A** result row as an associative array.  `A = 1`

Comment: use $rowteams = $result->fetch_array()

Comment: Each time you call `fetch_assoc()` you get the next row.  You called it once.  If you want to loop over the records, use it in a loop.

Comment: @MohitKumar: Just no...

Comment: I would love to loop through it but array only has one row... sad.. only has jay, nothing else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop and get all the data like so

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    //code
}
```